# Unable to get window handle, Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-7, interop, activex

I upgraded my development machine to Windows 7 and my project to .NET 3.5. When I try to run the project, I now get this error:

```
Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxVt' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.
```

The project is using the Dart Emulation for ActiveX Vt control, which emulates a terminal control. I double-checked and the program launches fine under Windows XP SP2 with .NET 3.5, so it's not the Framework causing the issue. Setting compatibility mode to Windows XP SP2 doesn't help either. This exception occurs when the designer code calls EndInit on the control.

Is there any way to work around this or does it just mean I have to remove Windows 7 from my machine and go back to Windows XP?

Comment: I've had this happen with objects from ESRI's ArcGIS Engine components. The only thing that fixed it was to create a brand new project and re-add everything again manually (which, of course, just means I was never able to figure out what caused the problem but could work around it).

Comment: I tried that out, adding just the Dart Vt control and running it and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching DEP off just to see if is that issue, I had it before, check here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2007/12/14/nxcompat-and-the-c-compiler.aspx
to find out how.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It is quite likely that the third party control you're using doesn't (yet) work with Windows 7, since it's still in beta.  Have you checked with the maker?

Most software implemented on top of both COM and the Windows APIs is likely to end up with difficulties when switching between versions of Windows, particularly versions that didn't exist when the software was written.  Hopefully, with a bit of time, the company making the product will have a hotfix or update for you.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I haven't checked with them since we're out of our support period. I did download the latest release of the control and I still encounter the problem. I was really hoping I wouldn't have to go back to XP, but it looks like I will.