# Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxSixBarcodeReader' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not support. Help me pls

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl0Hp.png)

Help me about this problem I can't fix it. I don't know why it is broken.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989663/unable-to-get-window-handle-windowless-activex-controls-are-not-supported maybe?

Comment: @AKX No, the error is still exists.